# Is there a more concise way of writing this code

Tags: ruby

I have just written this ruby code, it's very simple, I just want to swap the order of operation dependant on a variable. I have a feeling that what I've written is more verbose than it needs to be, can anyone think of a more concise way of writing it?

```
if opts["--appears"]
  if regex = opts["--matches"]
    test = !response.text.match(regex)
  else
    test = !response.empty?
  end
else
  if regex = opts["--matches"]
    test = response.text.match(regex)
  else
    test = response.empty?
  end
end
```

So what I think can be optimised is the outer if block, all that changes is it turns `test` into `!test`. Apologies for what seems to be a simple question but I just can't think of what to do to optimise it.

Let me know if you think this a bad forum for this question or whether you think it should be moved to code review. I was thinking this might be the best place for it but wasn't sure.

Thanks

Comment: This would be better asked on [codereview.se]. Stack Overflow is for questions dealing with problems with code. Code Review is for questions about improving code.

Comment: Thanks, @theTinMan I wasn't sure which is why I asked in the last sentence, I'll post there in future (I thought it was somewhat borderline and couldn't decide).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple improvement is to run your test first, and then return the negative if opts["--appears"]:

```
test = if regex = opts["--matches"]
  response.text.match(regex)
else
  response.empty?
end

opts["--appears"] ? !test : test
```

Comment: Or combine the first if/else into a ternary operator also

Comment: Ahh, thank you, I knew there was something very obvious, much appreciated. :)

Comment: @staticx I'm not sure that would improve the readability of the code though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would both simplify the code and improve readability:

```
regex = opts["--matches"]
test =
  if opts["--appears"]
    regex ? !response.text.match(regex) : !response.empty?
  else
    regex ? response.text.match(regex)  : response.empty?
  end
```

or, if you prefer:

```
regex = opts["--matches"]
test =
  case opts["--appears"]
  when true
    regex ? !response.text.match(regex) : !response.empty?
  when false
    regex ? response.text.match(regex)  : response.empty?
  end
```